# How to Mock private method in Class?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

In Nestjs, I would like to mock a service private method. In jest, with `spyOn` method, I can't access the private methods. How to do in that case?

**operation.service.ts**

```js
private async _getOperationDocument(id): Promise<OperationDocument> {
  return await this.operationDocumentService.findById(id);
}
```

**operation.service.spec.ts**

```js
jest
  .spyOn(service, '_getOperationDocument')
  .mockImplementation(async id => {
    return OperationDocumentMock as OperationDocument;
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrei-Dragotoniu I ended up to mock the service instead.

```js
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [{
   provide: OperationDocumentService,
   useValue: {
     findById: () => OperationDocumentMock,
   },
 }]
});
```

The private method is already called in another tested method.

Comment: Could you flag the answer as accepted if it solved your question please :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Since it's my own answer I have to wait til tomorrow to do so ;) (But I will)

Answer (score 1):

2 things from me.

1. You have a one line method which simply calls another one. I'd say you don't need this method at all, you are adding useless layers, complicating the code for no benefit at all.
2. even if you do end up keeping it, there's no point in mocking it. You might as well mock the method it's calling instead.

Comment: 1. There is other logic in the method. I simplified it for the question.
2. You're right, I mocked the called service instead.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this to remove the compile error:

```js
jest
  .spyOn(service, <any>'_getOperationDocument')
  .mockImplementation(async id => {
    return OperationDocumentMock as OperationDocument;
  });
```